# How can I permanently change PATH variable in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: user-profile

How can I permanently change PATH variable in Ubuntu 20.04?

What file should I modify?

Thank You

Comment: change or extend?

Answer (score 2):

You can just add it to your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc or ~/.THESHELLYOUHAVErc

like adding :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/some-new/:./another
```

changing might be more like

```
export PATH=yourneed1/:yourneed2/
```

without the existing one $PATH

but you need to adapt that to your own needs

you have to logout or reload the file `source ~/.profile` once, it is not instantly done ;) *(similar with .bashrc)*

Comment: Adding to .profile            export PATH=$PATH:/directory       , doesn't work.

Comment: you have to logout or reload the file `source ~/.profile`  it is not instantly done ;) I forgot to comment that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer